# Compress Video audio images on laravel before uploading

Tags: php, laravel, compression

Hi there I need your help, how is it possible to compress a video before uploading for example I put the validation of the video to be 10mb, but what I need is I browse a video with the size 12mb and upload it while compressing it so before uploading compress the video make smaller than 10mb and than go ahead and upload it. Is there a way on Laravel to do this..? Any plugins or can you help me somehow?

Comment: You can't compress the video before it reaches the server, with PHP at least. There are [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316791/compress-a-video-on-client-side-web) using javascript. Alternatively, you can not put an upload limit on the video and compress it server side.